# How to resolved Call to a member function query() on a non-object in php?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am calling function from URL and I am getting error Call to a member function `query()` on a non-object in this line( `$result =$conn->query($sql);`).My database connection is perfect. I am retrieving records from one table and inserting in second table. My `SQL` query is working.Would you help me in this?

```
URl:-http://domain.com/admin/delete.php?function=restore&res_id=7

$id = $_GET['res_id']; //retrive id from URL

include('db/connection.php');
switch($_GET['function']) {
    case 'delete':delete();break;
    case 'restore':restore();break;
    default : redirect('index.php');
}

function restore(){
    $sql="INSERT INTO request(Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no) SELECT Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no FROM trash WHERE Id=$id";
    $result =$conn->query($sql);
$delete="DELETE FROM trash  WHERE  Id='$id'";
    if ($conn->query($delete) === TRUE) {
        header('Location:dashboard.php?submitted=1');
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using  `mysqli_connect`  function?

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Didar,Please check my connection, $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

Comment: pass $conn variable to restore function like restore($conn) and change function restore(){ to function restore($conn){...hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Aamir, I am getting error now "Missing argument 1 for restore()"

Comment: use `var_dump($conn);` to check if connection exists there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass $conn variable to restore function e.g

restore($conn)

and change function

function restore(){

to

function restore($conn){

and

case 'restore':restore();break;

to

case 'restore':restore($conn);break;

...hope it will help you

Below is your updated code

```
URl:-http://domain.com/admin/delete.php?function=restore&res_id=7

$id = $_GET['res_id']; //retrive id from URL

include('db/connection.php');
switch($_GET['function']) {
    case 'delete':delete();break;
    case 'restore':restore($conn);break; //case 'restore':restore();break;
    default : redirect('index.php');
}

function restore($conn){ //function restore(){
    $sql="INSERT INTO request(Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no) SELECT Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no FROM trash WHERE Id=$id";
    $result =$conn->query($sql);
    if ($conn->query($delete) === TRUE) {
        header('Location:dashboard.php?submitted=1');
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Also change

$sql="INSERT INTO request(Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no) SELECT Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no FROM trash WHERE Id=$id";

with

$sql="INSERT INTO request(Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no) SELECT Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no FROM trash WHERE Id=". (int)$_GET['res_id'];

Comment: Thanks for Reply Mr.Aamir, Error goes off but inside a function, my query is not working.

Comment: Cool!!! now it's working. I added $id = $_GET['res_id']; inside function which you suggested me and working perfectly.Thanks for your help. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your problem.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'stakcoverflow');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
            . $conn->connect_error);
}

/*
 * Use this instead of $connect_error if you need to ensure
 * compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//echo 'Success... ' . $conn->host_info . "\n";

function restore($conn){ //function restore(){
    $id = 1;
    echo $sql="INSERT INTO request(Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no) SELECT Id, Name, Email, Mobile_no FROM trash WHERE Id=".$id."";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

if(restore($conn))
{
    echo "Success"; 
};

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Your problem is solve or not please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for help Mr.Didar but I am using Function with switch case

Comment: Okay, Using function is good.then you can call it how many times you need it. If my effort did help to you a little bit then please give me a vote. Thanks

Comment: Mr.Didar Can you help me with Function

Comment: Yes of course. But you need to provide the full page and your expectation output. That would be help full for me to give you a proper solution. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting error in this line $result =$conn->query($sql); Above code is full code.What you need it?

Comment: please wait a while

Comment: I have edited my answer. you have to call you db connection in your function because it's not under global scope.  `$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'stakcoverflow');`